# Why is a commented out $(error ...) in my Makefile getting triggered?

Tags: makefile, comments

This Makefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

wat:
    # $(error Hammer time)
```

...when run as `make wat` (with GNU Make), produces the output:

```
Makefile:4: *** Hammer time. Stop.
```

Why isn't it the line with `$(error ...)` ignored as a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put make comments in recipes, make simply parses the line and sends the result to the shell. In this case, because the `error` function terminates execution nothing is actually sent to the shell, the following illustrates what happens a little better perhaps

```
wat:
    # foo $(warning Hammer time)
```

produces:

```
Makefile:2: Hammer time
# foo
```

If you want to comment out a recipe line you will have to put `#` *before* the tab.

Comment: Ah, the `#` has to go at the start of the line! It all makes sense. You know, as much as anything about GNU Make makes sense.